# Variable change does not update on 2nd file

Tags: python

Im using 2 files here. Say the variable is in the 1st file and Im using it on the 2nd. It has the initialized value of it but when I change its value the 2nd file does not recognize it. How can I update the variable so that the 2nd file reads its current value?
first module:

```
var = 0

def plus():
    global var
    var += 1
    print(var)
```

second module(used tkinter for example)

```
from tkinter import *
from kk import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400+15+15")
btn = Button(root, text = "1", command = plus)
btn.pack()

def pr():
    print(var)

btn1 = Button(root, text = "2", command = pr)
btn1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you add some code showing what you are trying to do ? It sounds like you are doing `from first_file import variable` from `the second_file`. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Done, printing var inside the second module does not work after changed in the 1st one

Comment: When you do `from kk import var` (or `import *`) you are effectively copying the variable value from the other module. I think you would need to use an object wrapper to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from my comment, when you do `from kk import var` (or `import *`) you are effectively copying the variable value from the other module.

You need to copy a reference to the same object (instead of its value), you can achieve this using an object wrapper.

Try this:

```
class VarWrapper:
    def __init__(self, initial_value):
        self._value = initial_value

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._value)


var = VarWrapper(0)


def plus():
    global var
    var._value += 1
    print(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt seem like you called plus(), if you call it it might work
#revision
perhaps if you do this?

```
def update ():
    varInternal = var
def plusInternal ():
    plus()
    update()
```

Comment: There are 2 buttons. One to call plus from the 1st module and one to call pr from the SECOND module. calling plus truely changes the value but when calling afterwards pr it just prints the value it started at, before changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the first file function and execute it.
suppose first file name is first.py then import in second file.

```
from first import *
```

then it will work.

now you have access to first file. and to update variable use plus function.

Comment: Can't follow,
First file name is kk
Second is test
Where to put what again?

Answer (score 0):

I tried just importing again the wanted variable inside pr like so

```
def pr():
    from kk import var
    print(var)
```

It works, however I want to know if this way is appropriate to conventions